# Manipulação de dados com R

Tags: r

Olá, tenho um data frame de dados escolares e preciso calcular o número de evasão. O programa seria mais ou menos isso, só que desta forma demora muito tempo para terminar de executar. Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer ele de outra forma usando alguma biblioteca (de preferência `ddply`)?

```
Evasao <- function(row1, df){
  for(row2 in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(df[row1,"Id"] == df[row2,"Id"] & (df[row2, "NU_ANO_CENSO"]+1) == df[row1, "NU_ANO_CENSO"])
      FALSE
  }
  TRUE
}

#1 - evasão, 2 - não evasão
df <- dados_padronizados_ensino_medio_com_eja_2007_a_2018_com_id
df$EVASAO <- 0
for(row in 1:nrow(df)){
  #print(df["TP_ETAPA_ENSINO"])
  if(df[row,"TP_ETAPA_ENSINO"] == 25 | df[row,"TP_ETAPA_ENSINO"] == 26 ){
    if(Evasao(row, df)){
      df[row,"EVASAO"] <- 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tente fazer `Evasao <- cmpfun(Evasao)` e após vc ter criado a função Evasao. Ele cria uma versão compilada mais baixo nível que a sua Evasao, e compare o tempo computacional. E retorne aqui, bl?

Comment: @GuilhermeParreira vlw cara! Vou tentar aqui

Comment: Você pode explicar um pouco dos testes da função? Ou postar um `dput(head(dados))`? Que deve dar pra melhorar com alguma operação vetorizada no lugar dos for

Comment: O código da pergunta parece ser um caso claro de código facilmente vetorizável. Não precisa de ciclos `for` de certeza, nem  (quase de certeza) de `cmpfun` para ser *muito* mais rápido. Mas precisamos de dados de teste.

Comment: Esse código parece ter sido escrito por um programador não acostumado com o r, dá pra substituir essa checagens do row passado com alguma função de lag ou lead por exemplo

Comment: Olá @RuiBarradas, quando que seria interessante usar o `cmpfun`? Uma vez o meu amigo utilizou isso, e o código dele ficou bem mais rápido (as funções dele envolviam integração de laplace e otimização). Quando tentei em aplicar numa função que eu criei, em que comparo 7 diferentes métodos de previsão via `forecast` package, não tive ganho computacional